# Integral operator and powers of it (?)

Tags: integration, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I have a question about linear operators.

Let $X$ be the complex normed space $C([a, b])$ of continuous complex-valued functions on the closed bounded interval $[a,b]$, with the sup norm. For $x \in X$ I define $Tx$ by the relation

$$(Tx)(t)=\int_{a}^{t}x(s)ds$$

One can then show that in this case $||T|| = b-a$.

What I am supposed to find are functions $k_n$ from $\{ (s, t) | a \leq s \leq t \leq b \}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$(T^nx)(t)=\int_{a}^{t}k_n(s,t)x(s)ds$$

This is where I am stuck.
I tried to do the following for $n=2$:

$$(T^2x)(t)=\int_{a}^{t}(Tx)(s)ds = \int_{a}^{t}\int_{a}^{s}x(p)dpds$$

but can't seem to find a way to finish it.

Any help is appreciated, I'd prefer hints over full solutions, though.

Comment: $T^2x$ has two integrals in two different variables $dp \, ds$. Change the order of integration to $ds \, dp$. Then $x(p)$ can come out of the $ds$ integral.

Comment: And this is justified by Fubini's Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\int_{[a,t]\times[a,u]} |f(s)|\ \mathsf d(s\times u) \leqslant \|f\|_\infty(b-a)^2<\infty, 
$$
by Fubini's theorem we have
\begin{align}
T^2f(t) &= \int_a^t\int_a^u f(s)\ \mathsf ds\ \mathsf du\\
&= \int_a^t f(s) \int_s^t \ \mathsf du \ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_a^t (t-s)f(s)\ \mathsf ds.
\end{align}
Assume now that $T^nf(t) = \int_a^t \frac{(t-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f(s)\ \mathsf ds$ for some $n\geqslant 1$. Then
\begin{align}
T^{n+1}f(t) &= \int_a^t \int_a^u \frac{(u-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f(s)\ \mathsf ds\ \mathsf du\\
&= \int_a^t f(s)\int_s^t \frac{(u-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ \mathsf du \ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_a^t \frac{(t-s)^n}{n!}f(s)\ \mathsf ds.
\end{align}
It follows by induction that $$k_n(s,t) = \frac{(t-s)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

Comment: Can you explain why if we change the order of integration we have to change the limits of the second integral, too, please? I think I don't fully understand Fubini's Theorem

Comment: Is that since we want $s \leq u$?

Comment: @asdf It helps to sketch the region $[a,t]^2$ in the $s$-$u$ plane with $u\leqslant s$.